# Is it worth paying Experian to remove personal information?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

I hit the "**Scan the dark web**" button on the Experian web site.

I got:

[image]

Is this really an issue and if so is this worth upgrading my account?

Comment: Is this in the US?

Comment: Note they are trying to sell you something, and that makes them untrustworthy.

Comment: "It won't prevent them from resurfacing your info later." So what's the benefit of *paying* to remove it temporarily? And these are just the "dark web" sites that don't bother to hide themselves from places like Experian.

Comment: "personal info" could mean many different things. My name and address are "personal" but anybody can view public mortgage records and find me. Does Experian tell you what info is "exposed"?

Comment: @littleadv  Yes, USA

Comment: @Nosjack No, all that is grayed out and I assume you won't know until you purchase the upgrade.

Comment: This is a really subjective question. Whether or not a purchase is "worth it" highly depends on your personal situation and finances. I think the key thing to consider here is that all they do is "request" removal, which you can do yourself. And they point out that these sites may re-publish your data later.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in the USA you should not expect any privacy. Your info is sold by everyone to everyone. The sites Experian refers to are data aggregators that find information about you online, aggregate it, and re-sell it to anyone (including you, when you ask to remove it). These are not "dark web" sites selling leaked data. Everything aggregated on these sites is available from some public record, so removing it from these sites won't remove the data availability, it will just remove it from one specific aggregator (or how many that Experian pays off).

Whether or not it's an issue and whether or not it's worth a subscription is up to you.

Comment: Appreciate downvoters to comment.

Answer (score 0):

First off once your info hits the dark web it’s sold or auctioned for a fee depending on if the holder know you have something of value. Secondly there is not much you can do other than change and cancel what you have control over. There is far crazier things happening in the dark web( child pornography, hire for hitman, murder requests,etc..) which the FBI and other agency have worked tirelessly to eradicate l, very few success on their part. So yes it’s a scam to pay for your info to be removed, for which they might if sold themselves in the first place lol.